Spring oauth2 authorization serve with rest controller then secured the endpoint
This is the endpoint of the rest controller /info/** when i permit all its working but when i secured it then add token it wont work.
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();

        authorizationServerConfigurer.tokenIntrospectionEndpoint(a ->
                a.authenticationProvider(new CustomOAuth2TokenIntrospectionAuthenticationProvider(authorizationService())));
        httpSecurity.apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);


        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/info/**")).authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .addFilterBefore(logRequestResponseFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                ;
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }


Log
2024-05-09T00:00:26.883+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 401 UNAUTHORIZED
2024-05-09T00:00:26.890+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?userId=5532f935-ca36-4768-87fa-b65fe8741bbf
2024-05-09T00:00:26.893+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-05-09T00:00:26.894+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error?userId=5532f935-ca36-4768-87fa-b65fe8741bbf
2024-05-09T00:00:26.895+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?userId=5532f935-ca36-4768-87fa-b65fe8741bbf", parameters={masked}
2024-05-09T00:00:26.895+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-05-09T00:00:26.904+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2024-05-09T00:00:26.904+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Thu May 09 00:00:26 SGT 2024, status=401, error=Unauthorized, path=/info/}]
2024-05-09T00:00:26.910+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 401
2024-05-09T00:00:26.911+08:00 DEBUG 14264 --- [               ] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-05-09T00:00:26.911+08:00  INFO 14264 --- [               ] c.e.O.filter.LogRequestResponseFilter    : LoggingFilterRequestResponse: Servlet Path: /error Request parameter [Key: userId, Value: 5532f935-ca36-4768-87fa-b65fe8741bbf]  Response status code: 401 Response Body: {"timestamp":"2024-05-08T16:00:26.902+00:00","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","path":"/info/"}


Hi @Slevin , have added the log

Your security filter-chain is configured to authorize requests with sessions cookies (formLogin), not with access tokens.
You need an additional security filter-chain bean (with @Order, securityMatcher and oauth2ResourceServer) to authorize requests to some endpoints with Bearer tokens.
